# PapaParse streaming local file in chunks, Only load one chunk

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I'm having trouble making Papaparse to stream: I used the following code to load a local csv file in chunks:

```
Papa.parse(filename, {
        header: true,
        download: true,
        chunk: function(chunk) {
            console.log('loading chunk');
            for (var ii = 0; ii < chunk.length; ii++) {
                d = chunck.data[ii];
                overallData.push(d) 
                n = +d[density];
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log('papa load complete',overallData);
        }
    });
```

unfortunately it turns out "loading chunk" was only printed once, and no data was added to "overallData", any idea how to correct this code? thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to set `Papa.RemoteChunkSize`.  https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config

Comment: @Paul Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried both ways here: https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/673 for both remote and local chunk size, none worked unfortunately..